# How to get edges after vertices in a graph using TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

The following code is giving me a graph, how to display edges one after the other instead of displaying total graph at a time.

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [scale=.8,auto=left,every node/.style={circle,fill=blue!20}]
  %\node (n6) at (1,10) {6};
  \node (n4) at (3,4)  {4};
  \node (n5) at (3,2)  {5};
  \node (n1) at (1.5,2)  {1};
  \node (n2) at (3,6)  {2};
  \node (n3) at (4.5,2)  {3};

  \foreach \from/\to in {n2/n4,n4/n3,n4/n5,n4/n1}
    \draw (\from) -- (\to);
\draw (n2) to [out=-20,in=35] (n3);
\draw (n2) to [out=200,in=135] (n1);
\draw (n2) to [out=-20,in=35] (n5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Closure of a Tree}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you indent your code by four white spaces, it will be shown as code. Or you mark it and press the {}-Button. Please complete your code by your documentclass and the packages you need to compile this. With that, it is easier for us to help.

Comment: Are you using `beamer`?

Comment: @Medina I am using beamer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the fact that TikZ commands are overlat aware (I used `\visible` for the bended arrows to prevent the figure from "jumping around"):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [scale=.8,auto=left,every node/.style={circle,fill=blue!20}]
  %\node (n6) at (1,10) {6};
  \node (n4) at (3,4)  {4};
  \node (n5) at (3,2)  {5};
  \node (n1) at (1.5,2)  {1};
  \node (n2) at (3,6)  {2};
  \node (n3) at (4.5,2)  {3};

  \foreach \from/\to [count=\xi from 2] in {n2/n4,n4/n3,n4/n5,n4/n1}
    \draw<\xi-> (\from) -- (\to);
\visible<6->{\draw (n2) to [out=-20,in=35] (n3);}
\visible<7->{\draw (n2) to [out=200,in=135] (n1);}
\draw<8-> (n2) to [out=-20,in=35] (n5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Closure of a Tree}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please delete convert -verbose -delay 50 -loop 0 -density 300 <file>-crop.pdf <file>.gif from source ;-)

Comment: @L.Humbert Done. Thanks! I don't know how the conversion code made it to the code :)